# Laravel: same table relationship error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing a directory hierarchy with JSTree.

I am setting up database columns and relatioships with the Schema builder.
here's what I have.

```
 Schema::create('directories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('text');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->default(0)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('directories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

during migration I get no error, but when I try to insert a record I get the error saying

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('dms'.'directories', CONSTRAINT 'directories_parent_id_foreign' FOREIGN KEY ('parent_id') REFERENCES 'directories' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into 'directories' ('name', 'text', 'parent_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (Project, Project, 0, 2018-01-20 12:50:37, 2018-01-20 12:50:37))`

what could be wrong with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `set` a foreign key to `0`, rather provide a real id as `parent_id` from `directories` Or you could change your schema to following to allow `null` as `parent_id`.

```
Schema::create('directories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('text');
    $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('directories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();

});
```

And in your `insert` method, you can skip `parent_id` or set to `null`.

Comment: if I use `signed()` can I use zero as foreign key?

Comment: no, sign value refer to negative value too but foreign key can't be negative, so i would suggest keep it null, this way you can query without error, keeping zero will need additional check when you will retrieve value from this relation